# Extensions may not contain stored properties in UItextfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift-extensions

```
extension UITextField
@IBInspectable var placeholdercolor: UIColor 
    {
    willSet {
         attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder != nil ?  placeholder! : "", attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: placeholdercolor])
    }}
```

I am creating extension for UITextField for placeholder colour . I don't want to create custom class and  I also try

```
@IBInspectable var placeholdercolor: UIColor 
    {
get
    {
       return self.placeholdercolor 
    }
    set
    {
        attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder != nil ?  placeholder! : "", attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: placeholdercolor])
    }
}
```

but it is giving error (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS) on method

```
get
    {
       return self.placeholdercolor 
    }
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBInspectable var placeholdercolor: UIColor 
    {
get
    { // you can't return this here because this will call the getter again and again -> Stack Overflow
       return self.placeholdercolor 
    }
    set
    {
        attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder != nil ?  placeholder! : "", attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: placeholdercolor])
    }
}
```

What you should instead in the getter is return the foreground color attribute in the attributed string:

```
get
    {
       return attributedPlaceholder?.attribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) as? UIColor
    }
```

I suggest you make this property an optional just in case the property is not set.

EDIT:

Your setter is also incorrect. You should use `newValue`:

```
attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder != nil ?  placeholder! : "", attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: newValue])
```